# How to rigorously put back dimensions in equations involving natural units?

Tags: special-relativity, dimensional-analysis, absolute-units

I was watching the first lecture of Special Relativity by Leonerd Susskind (link:[Youtube](https://youtu.be/toGH5BdgRZ4?t=995)) whereby setting the speed of light to 1, i.e. $c = 1 \dfrac{[l]}{[s]}$, where $[l] = 3 \cdot 10^8 [m]$, we get one of the Lorentz transforms as:
\begin{equation}
x^{'} = \dfrac{x-vt}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} \tag1
\end{equation}
Now, I am very confused about how he would just hand waive to justify transforming this equation into:
$$
x^{'} = \dfrac{x-vt}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}} \tag2
$$
Like I tried multiple things with dimension analysis to understand this. For example, if we set $u = \dfrac{v}{c}$ (dimensionless velocity) then, $v=uc$, and hence we get:
$$
x^{'} = \dfrac{x-u(ct)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \tag3
$$
So, it would make sense to define $\tau = ct$ with units of $[l]$. This would then get us basically eq. 1, but the speed of light here would be $c = x\tau [m][l]$ which doesn't make sense. HELP. I need a rigorous way to understand this.

Comment: Your expression for $[l]$ doesn't seem to make sense. Notice you are getting the speed of light to have dimensions of acceleration.

Comment: *just hand wave* On dimensional grounds, the terms in the numerator are fine; they already have the dimension of length and thus don’t need need any power of $c$ restored. The denominator then needs to be dimensionless, and the obvious way to do that is to divide the $v^2$ by $c^2$. Voilà. You don’t need rigor… you just need to be able to do dimensional analysis with ease. Learning how to hand wave a bit is a key part of physics education.

Comment: I have never tried to justify this “rigorously”…that’s overkill. For me, going to natural units means setting $c=1$ so that $c$ disappears for convenience. Going back to “normal” units like SI means using dimensional analysis to stick $c$’s back in wherever necessary to make “normal” units work. It’s *not* complicated. Think of it as a “clever hack”.

Comment: In addition to being convenient, natural units are better at revealing the essence of physics. $m^2=E^2-\mathbf p^2$ reveals that mass is the Lorentz-invariant length of the energy-momentum four-vector so much more elegantly than $m^2c^4=E^2-\mathbf p^2c^2$ does. Without that clutter of $c$’s, the Minkowskian geometry is in-your-face.

Answer (score 5):

It is tricky!

Let's see what happens in the example you asked about. The starting point is
$$
x^{'} = \dfrac{x-vt}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}. \tag1
$$
From the denominator on the right hand side we deduce that $v$ is dimensionless. It then follows that in the numerator, $x$ and $t$ must have the same dimensions. Therefore if we wish to adopt ordinary units where $x$ and $t$ do not both have the same dimensions, then one of them will have to be adjusted. What we need here is in fact
$$
v = u / c,  \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad t = c T
$$
which together give
$$
x^{'} = \dfrac{x - u T}{\sqrt{1 - u^2/c^2}}.
$$

More generally, putting the $c$'s back in requires methodical working through all parts of a formula, and I think it might not always be unambiguous. However, in an edit to this answer I now admit, on reflection, it is not easy to construct an ambiguous case so maybe it's unambiguous after all. The reason for possible ambiguity is that a $1$ in any formula might become a $c$ or a $c^2$ or other power so you have to watch out.

The lesson is that natural units are best adopted only once you confidently know what you are doing.

Comment: You can put $c^2$ in the denominator, it's then just a matter of adjusting the numerator.

Comment: "it is not always unambiguous" -- I agree it can be *confusing* for beginners (and sometimes experts!), but is it ever actually *ambiguous*? (eg: are there ever two ways of reintroducing units that are not equivalent?)

Comment: @Andrew I think it can be ambiguous but I don't have an example ready to hand. I will have to think a bit more.

Comment: @AndrewSteane OK, if you think of one I'd be interested! Naively I would think that if the only way there could be an ambiguity, is if there was a way to form a dimensionless combination of the constants you are setting equal to 1 in the original unit system. As a trivial example, if we set both the speed of sound and the speed of light equal to 1, that would be ambiguous.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that I'd be worried if the replacement was actually ambiguous, then that would imply an inconsistency in the equations. (Setting the speed of sound and speed of light equal to 1 simultaneously is inconsistent of course).

Comment: @Andrew There can of course be superficial ambiguity (e.g. $1/\sqrt{1-v^2} \mapsto 1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ vs $c/\sqrt{c^2-v^2}$) but I agree that unless the chosen unit system is inconsistent in the way you describe, then although there may be several *possible* "re-dimensionalizations" of an expression, they are all ultimately equivalent to one another.

Comment: @J.Murray Thanks. That's what I would expect.

Comment: @Andrew, Morin in his classical mechanics book actually mentions the same thing, that since c has units there must be only one way to put dimensions back

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin with your equation, where you have defined the conversion between natural and SI units. This is where you're making a mistake.
$$c=1\frac{[l]}{[s]}$$

So now you're defining the *natural length* with units
$$[l]=299792458 \frac{[m]}{[s]}$$

However, notice that your $[l]$ must have the units of length, and not speed. So this is where you went wrong... the simple correction here is that
$$[l]=299792458 [m]$$

This should solve your issue.